# Ellipsis width of the drop down selected item when an item with large name is selected

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I am using a third party library for multi select dropdown.
https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

I have the following settings

```
    selectSettings:IMultiSelectSettings = {
    enableSearch: true,
    checkedStyle: 'fontawesome',
    dynamicTitleMaxItems: 1,
    displayAllSelectedText: false
  };
```

If I select an item from dropdown that has a long name it runs out of the dropdown. I have set a fixed width for the dropdown. So my question is that if its possible to ellipsis the name if the selected name is too long rather than running out of the dropdown box? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work with your 3rd party library, but I use a truncate pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'truncate'
})
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, limit: number = 10, trail: string = '...'): string {
      return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
  }

}
```

An example of usage:

```
{{ name | truncate : 30 : '...' }}
```

This will take the text in the variable name and truncate it to 30 characters and then append a set of ellipses onto the end of the string.

Comment: <ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem">
              <span style="vertical-align:middle">{{ item.name | truncate : 30 : '...'}}</span>
          </ng-template>